# JQuery not working in Jade

Tags: jquery, pug

I was making a simple cart for my site.But JQuery is not working
Here's the code:

```
  head
    meta(charset="utf-8")
    link(href = "/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", rel = "stylesheet")
    script(src = "/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js")
    script(src = "/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js")
    script(src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js")
    script(src='./cart.js')
    style
        include style.css
                .cart-body
                    ul
                        -for(var i in Cart)
                            if(!Cart[i].cId)
                                continue
                            li
                                .li-checkbox
                                    input(data-id= '#{Cart[i].cId}', data-index= '{#i}', data-price='{#Carts[i].cPrice}', class="li-checkbox input" ,type= 'checkbox')
                                .li-img
                                    img(src="#{Cart[i].cImgSrc}")
                                .li-content
                                    a(herf= '/shop/#{item_id}') #{Cart[i].cName}
                                .li-price
                                    span #{Cart[i].cPrice}
                                .li-quantity
                                    a(data-type='add', herf= 'javascript:void(0);', class='btn btn-default btn-xs') +
                                    input(id= 'Q#{i}', style= 'width: 40px;', type= 'text', value= '#{Cart[i].cQuantity}')
                                    a(data-type='subtr' herf= 'javascript:void(0);', class='btn btn-default btn-xs') -
                                .li-del
                                    a(herf= '/delFromCart/#{Cart[i]._id}', class= 'btn btn-primary btn-xs') deleted
```

```js
//this is the part of JQuery
$(function() {
      $('.li-quantity').click(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        var type = self.attr('data-type'),
          num = parseFloat(self.siblings('input').val());
        if (type == 'add') {
          num += 1;
        } else if (type == 'subtr') {
          if (num > 1) {
            num -= 1;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
        self.siblings('input').val(num);
        tamount();
      });
```

RUN in Node with Express ! They told me my question is mostly code,so I paste some important code in the text

Comment: can you share the generated html?

Comment: Why you used two jQuery libs? here in head part i see you include two jquery.min.js

Comment: What do you mean by "jQuery is not working"? In what way is it not working (it is not being run, js file not included, the jquery code isn't doing what it is supposed to do)?

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting a div tag with your `$('.li-quantity')` command, and then reading its `data-type` attribute. But you added your `data-type` attribute to an internal hyperlink.

Change your code like so:

```
$('.li-quantity').click(function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var type = $('a[data-type]', self).attr('data-type'),
       num = parseFloat(self.siblings('input').val());
```

Comment: Thank for ur suggestion. not working meas the js file is not included.

Comment: So you mean `./cart.js` file is not being included? Are your jade and js file in the same directory? What is your folder structure? Also, could you please add rendered jade code as well?

Comment: Yes,they r in the same directory.I counterfeited data in app.js

Comment: Then, I guess the jade template is evaluated into a differ folder when you access them through the web/browser. Then, open your page and look into the dev tools inspector's "Network" tab. See if the cart.js file is being successfully loaded. If not, check the url it is trying to be accessed from.